# Capistrano 3 upload hangs

Tags: setup-deployment, capistrano3

After upgrading to capistrano 3 and solving a lot of trouble there is one thing I cant get working. The new upload functionality in  mij script hangs and capistrano wont continue. My original Capistrano 2.x script was partly created from examples I found on the web.

in my recipe:

```
  task :setup do
desc "Creates shared Config dir, uploads local config files."
on roles(:cake) do

  execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/Config"

  on fetch(:cake_config_files) do |cake_config_file|
    on roles(:cake) do
      execute "echo a"
      upload! "Config/#{cake_config_file}", "#{shared_path}/Config/#{cake_config_file}", :via => :scp
      execute "echo b"
    end
  end
end
```

end

The output:

```
 INFO [4f52db7e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/user/sites/myapp/test/shared/Config on myapp.nl
DEBUG [4f52db7e] Command: mkdir -p /home/user/sites/myapp/test/shared/Config
 INFO [4f52db7e] Finished in 0.601 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [69fff539] Running /usr/bin/env echo a on myapp.nl
 INFO [de58c44d] Running /usr/bin/env echo a on myapp.nl
 INFO [9f635a1a] Running /usr/bin/env echo a on myapp.nl
DEBUG [69fff539] Command: echo a
DEBUG [de58c44d] Command: echo a
DEBUG [9f635a1a] Command: echo a
 INFO [69fff539] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [69fff539]    a
 INFO [69fff539] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [de58c44d] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [de58c44d]    a
 INFO [de58c44d] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [9f635a1a] Finished in 0.075 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [9f635a1a]    a
 INFO [9f635a1a] Finished in 0.075 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

After this, nothing happens. The script just paused/ hangs. My test to echo a B does't do anything also ;)

note: I tried this with and without ':via => :scp' as argument og upload (in my original script i uses ':via => :scp')

Comment: Update:

Edited the line into:

    upload!("app/Config/#{cake_config_file}", "#{shared_path}/Config/#{cake_config_file}", :via => :scp)

This seems to work, although it is strange to me that the other line wont raise an error? (notice the app/ before Config. Thats because i moved my Capistrano scripts one level up.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/31275142/667127

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issues, when i found out the problem was my Rubinius installation. 
Changing to current MRI solved it for me. Kind regards